# Remove Google Chrome extension by a VBScript?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, vbscript

Is it possible to remove the extension on Google Chrome via a VBScript?

The extension is stored in the following folder,

> %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions

The extension data is stored in a JSON file called "Preferences" in the following folder location,

> %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

Furthermore, if the "Preferences" file is modified then Google Chrome detects it and resets the "Preferences" file. If we remove the lines where the specific extension data is stored in the "Preferences" file, it automatically resets that file and notifies the user when Google Chrome is opened. How to use VBScript to remove the extension and prevent Google Chrome from detecting it?

Comment: Have you tried any code? Deleting folders is quite easy in VBS. edit: oh I see the issue. You'd have to rip out the extension's settings from that JSON file, and vbScript doesn't really know about JSON. try www.aspjson.com

Comment: VBScript code can be used to delete the extension folder but it also needs to modify the JSON file too. I will check "www.aspjson.com" site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using VBScript to find and replace all multi-line text between curly braces of a node within a JSON file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588622/using-vbscript-to-find-and-replace-all-multi-line-text-between-curly-braces-of-a)