# Running a vbs script to enable or disable a chrome extension

Tags: vbscript

I have created the following script to enable or disable a chrome extension, the script runs perfectly until it tries to use {ENTER} on the enable or disable button. This action works manually on the keyboard and I have tried different sleep times between this command.

The button id is div#button, is there a way to get this working?

```
Dim shell
Set shell = wscript.CreateObject("Shell.Application")
set x = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
shell.Open "C:\Users\steve.newton\Desktop\Google Chrome.lnk"
WScript.Sleep 1000  
x.sendkeys("chrome://extensions/")
WScript.Sleep 1000
x.sendkeys"{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep 800
x.sendkeys"{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 100
x.sendkeys"{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 100
x.sendkeys"{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 100
x.sendkeys"{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 100
x.sendkeys"{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 400
x.sendkeys"{ENTER}"
```

Answer (score 1):

[[Remove Google Chrome extension by a VBScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25825179/remove-google-chrome-extension-by-a-vbscript]) - your solution in different thread, also refer one more thread 
[[Using VBScript to find and replace all multi-line text between curly braces of a node within a JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588622/using-vbscript-to-find-and-replace-all-multi-line-text-between-curly-braces-of-a])

Comment: I do not want to remove it I need to turn it on and off via the vbs script

Comment: Launch Chrome with extension parameter through shellobject in vbscript may help you. Example: launch chrome with cmd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -no-first-run --load-extension="extension path"