# dysfunctional regex based vbscript being used to append multiple lines of text at a specific location in a .c file

Tags: regex, vbscript, wsh

I am learning regex and vbscript in order to append text to a .c file on a new line by adding user inputted text on a monthly basis. I removed the *positive lookbehind assertion* '?<=' from my pattern to void the syntax error from my previous post:

[Regular expression syntax error code: 800A1399](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34725788/regular-expression-syntax-error-code-800a1399/34729111?noredirect=1#comment57207896_34729111)

This is the modified pattern:

```
re.Pattern = "(loss_pct_through_([a-zA-Z]{3,5}\d{4})\[([a-zA-Z_]{1,2}\d{1,2})\]\s=\s\d\.\d{14}[;]\n)\n(?=\}\n)"
```

Now I have a script run, but it does not meet its intended purpose as user input related text to be generated by the following code does not append to the .c file.

```
path = "<C:\Users\Parth\Desktop\C06S3000.C>"
set re = new regexp 

Set objfso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objfso.FileExists(path) Then
  Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(path).ReadAll
End If

inputstr3 = inputbox("enter names of affected groups")`
grpString1 = split(inputstr3, ",")`

inputstr4 = inputbox("enter loss percentage")`
grpString2 = split(inputstr4, ",")`

ublptm = ubound(grpString1)
    for i=0 to ublptm 'where lptm = loss_pct_avg_monthyear[group] = percent;'
      lptmStr = lptmstr + "loss_pct_through_[" & grpString1(i) & "] = " & grpString2(i) & ";" & vbCrLf  
    next

re.Pattern = "(loss_pct_through_([a-zA-Z]{3,5}\d{4})\[([a-zA-Z_]{1,2}\d{1,2})\]\s=\s\d\.\d{14}[;]\n)\n(?=\}\n)"

objFile = re.Replace(objFile, vbCrLf & lptmstr & vbCrLf)
```

For reference, the .c file is supposed to be updated like so:

Original file:

```
 loss_pct_through_nov2015[a4] = 0.13155605112872;
 loss_pct_through_nov2015[a5] = 0.23415898757080;

 loss_pct_through_dec2015[a2] = 0.00283148378304;
 loss_pct_through_dec2015[a3] = 0.39331380134641;
 loss_pct_through_dec2015[a4] = 0.56333929692615;
 loss_pct_through_dec2015[a5] = 0.04051541794440; <-append content from here
\n <-regex search for this newline character
}
```

Updated file:

```
 loss_pct_through_nov2015[a4] = 0.13155605112872;
 loss_pct_through_nov2015[a5] = 0.23415898757080;

 loss_pct_through_dec2015[a2] = 0.00283148378304;
 loss_pct_through_dec2015[a3] = 0.39331380134641;
 loss_pct_through_dec2015[a4] = 0.56333929692615;
 loss_pct_through_dec2015[a5] = 0.04051541794440;   
\n <--new newline character replacing the old one to append content below
 loss_pct_through_jan2016[a2] = 0.04051541794440;
 loss_pct_through_jan2016[a4] = 0.04051541794440;

}
```

Comment: I think you should have asked the person who answered you in the previous post in the first place. This code here is incomplete. Please provide an [MVCE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you for the input. Does this edition satisfy MVCE condition?

Comment: That is rather much more than is necessary. So, you have "original file" (input), you have "updated" file, that is expected output, right? `lptmstr` looks to be some value you build dynamically from user input. Hm. Try [`(loss_pct_through_([a-zA-Z]{3,5}\d{4})\[([a-zA-Z_]{1,2}\d{1,2})\]\s=\s\d\.\d{14};\n)\n(?=\s*\})`](https://regex101.com/r/kA2yQ7/1) with `$0YOUR_REPLACEMENT\n` as replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing this code:

```
If objfso.FileExists(path) Then
  Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(path).ReadAll
End If
```

should give you an error, because you're reading a string from a file, but try to assign it to a variable using the `Set` keyword, which is only for assigning objects.

If you don't get an error you most likely have an `On Error Resume Next` in your code. Remove that.

Change the above code to this so that you a) have a proper assignment, and b) don't use a misleading variable name:

```
If objfso.FileExists(path) Then
  txt = objFSO.OpenTextFile(path).ReadAll
End If
```

Also, I'd suspect that your regular expression doesn't match what you think it matches. Your input file seems to have linebreaks encoded as CR-LF, since you're adding linebreaks as `vbCrLf`. In your regular expression, however, you're using `\n`, which matches only LF. Change that to `\r\n` (and also remove the pointless groups and assertions):

```
re.Pattern = "(loss_pct_through_[a-zA-Z]{3,5}\d{4}\[[a-zA-Z_]{1,2}\d{1,2}\]\s=\s\d\.\d{14};\r\n\r\n)(\}\r\n)"
```

and do the replacement like this:

```
txt = re.Replace(txt, "$1" & lptmstr & vbCrLf & "$2")
```

so that the new string is inserted between the last line and the closing curly bracket.

And don't forget to write the modified string back to the file:

```
objFSO.OpenTextFile(path, 2).Write txt
```

Comment: Thank you for the corrections. Could you provide some info about "$1" and "$2" in re.Replace(txt, "$1" & lptmstr & vbCrLf & "$2")? 

I've seen similar code in many examples, but don't understand its purpose.

Comment: They're backreferences to the first and second group in the pattern. Backreferences are used to preserve grouped matches in a replacement.